# Правильное ударение: "творОг", "твОрог"

Tags: ударение

Правда ли, что допустимы оба ударения: и "творОг", и "твОрог"? Мне всегда казалось, что "твОрог" — это неграмотно.

Comment: В словарях допускается ударение как на первый слог, так и на второй.

Comment: Интересно  и  то,  что  появлением  нового  продукта  название  поменялось  у  старого.  Почему  не  наоборот ?

Comment: Да, это действительно любопытно. Хотя можно объяснить. Какое-то время "старый" сыр, видимо, называли крестьянским или домашним сыром (не знаю точно, это предположение), а "новый" - голландским или как-то ещё. Т.е. "старый" и "новый" как бы уравняли в "лингвистических правах". И на ткакой из продуктов падет выбор для нового названия - стало делом случая. 
Кстати, название "новое" - тоже с оговоркой. Оно идет от общеславянского морфа со значением "творить", "тварь".

Comment: Как  говорил  Ниро  Вулф - приемлемо. Может  ближайшим  по  смыслу  будет  слово  "затворить"  или  "створожить",  если  это  слово  существовало  как  обозначение  процесса  приготовления.  Как  считаете ?

Comment: Не знаю. А зачем оно? Факт родственности "творог" и "творить" сомнению не подвргается, а было ли промежеточным "затворить" или "створожить" - и было ли - как-то не представляется значимым.

Comment: Ясно. Не  могу  проголосовать  за  ваш  ответ - знаков  уважения  не  хватает. Я  ошибочно  предположил, что  название  поменялось  у  старого  продукта.  Наоборот - полузабытым  "сыр"  назвали  новый  продукт. А  влияние  украинского  и  польского  тоже  должно  было  быть.

Comment: Вообще-то действительно существует домашний сыр. И его так называют до сих пор. Причем такой творог можно купить в магазине. См. сами:
http://foodle.ru/sites/default/files/imagecache/product_full/1001158b.jpg
http://www.vezet.me/katalog/dostavka-s/okej/moloko-i-molokoprodukty/tvorog/6408432095238
http://irecommend.ru/sites/default/files/user-images/46074/p1040459.jpg

Comment: Как в магазине спрашивать : Дайте мне килограмм твОрога? Или нет.

Comment: >Как в магазине спрашивать : Дайте мне килограмм твОрога? Или нет.

Присоединюсь к вопросу Grumant'a. 

Если в именительном падеже возможны варианты с ударением: творОг и твОрог, то как в других падежах? 

Ударение только на первый слог? ТвОрога и т.п.?

Comment: Нет. ТворОг-творогА-творогУ и т.д.
ТвОрог-твОрога-твОрогу и т.д.

Самое смешное, что я иногда говорю творОг и твОрога, что никак не модет быть признано правильным. Но поскольку на слух это не устанавливается, то и поймать невозможно. 
А вот причины мне установить трудно. Видимо из разных источников почерпнул в действе.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Русский вариант - творОг. Польский - твОрог. Оба считаются правильными.
История такая. На Руси до появления при Петре твердых (сычужных) сыров творог называли сыром. С появлением нового кушанья понятия потребовалось как-то разделить.
Воспользовались словом, которое в русском языке почти забылось, а в польском и украинском существовало. Поэтому ударение двоякое.

Comment: А по-украински "творог" так и будет — "сир" (читается "сыр")

Comment: Да, я знаю. Самое-то интересное, что по-польски сейчас тоже ser. И сыр, и творог. Tworóg осталось только как имя собственное (топоним и фамилия).
Так что "творог" сейчас сохранилось именно в русском.

Comment: По-польски на творог можно сказать и twaróg, и biały ser.

Comment: Да? Спасибо. Значит, а в букве ошибся.