# О сыре и твороге

Tags: лексика

**Фактическая история**

**История творога** http://ogorodland.ru/kulinarnye-sovety/tvorog-istoriya-proisxozhdeniya-tvoroga/

Он был в широком употреблении за несколько столетий до появления в России сыра. Но наши предки называли творог сыром. Даже после появления в России сычужных сыров их стали называть губчатыми сырами, а творог еще долгое время называли просто сыром. Во всяком случае, еще в XVII веке слово 'творог' не употреблялось. http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/998551-kogda-vpervye-stali-gotovit-tvorog-i-chem-on-polezen.html

**История сыра** https://masterok.livejournal.com/4107105.html

Создать сыроваренную отрасль на государственном уровне первым попытался Пётр I. Из своего Великого посольства царь привёз голландских сыроделов. Главной задачей иностранных экспертов было накормить сычужным сыром двор, но в перспективе Пётр планировал наладить его массовое производство. Тогда его идее не суждено было сбыться. Историки сыроварения объясняют это секретностью рецептуры: иностранцы, мол, охотно делали сыры в России сами, но технологию не раскрывали.

В 1812 году князь Иван Мещерский открыл в своём имении в селе Лотошино первую крупную сырную фабрику.  [http://домашний-сыр.рф/o-syre/1.html](http://%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%8B%D1%80.%D1%80%D1%84/o-syre/1.html)

**Лингвистическая история**

Итак, еще в XVII веке слово «творог» не употреблялось.  У Черных: В памятниках др.-рус. письменности не обнаружено. В 1618 году зафиксировано слово «творожено» у Р. Джемса со значением «кислое молоко». О.-с. основа tvorogъ (от tvoriti),  в славянских языках слово встречается с ударением на втором слоге. Больше никаких сведений не приводится, хотя Черных обычно пишет, когда и где слово упоминается впервые.

**И вопросы:**

1) Когда слово «творог» появилось в русском языке (а) в книжных памятниках и (б) в словарях  в современном значении? Из какого языка оно заимствовано?

2) Почему ударение постепенно смещается на **первый** слог? (Сначала этот вариант был диалектным или просторечным, потом стал допускаться, а сейчас считается равноправным с ударением на первом слоге).

3) Можно определить частотность употребления для двух вариантов?

**Обсуждение ударения на форуме**

[Правильное ударение: "творОг", "твОрог"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8412/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%9E%D0%B3-%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%9E%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3)

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**Интересную информацию можно найти в Нацкорпусе.**

Сено, дрова, уголье, масло, даже **молоко и творог**, огородные овощи, овес, ячмень, ягоды, грибы не изключая, суть товары окружных С.-Петербурга селений. [А. Н. Радищев. [Записка о податях Петербургской губернии] (1786-1788)]

На горе Шейдеке нашел я пастухов, которые также потчевали меня **творогом, сыром** и густыми, ароматическими сливками. [Н. М. Карамзин. Письма русского путешественника (1793)]

В нем сыр, **или, говоря по-петербургски, творог**, и недоеденные ломти хлеба… [Г. Ф. Квитка-Основьяненко. Пан Халявский (1839)]

После того уже узнали, что в Петербурге, где все идет деликатро и манерно, **наш настоящий сыр называется "творог"**. [Г. Ф. Квитка-Основьяненко. Пан Халявский (1839)]

Получается, что слово ***творог*** появилось в речи в XVIII веке (когда именно?), но распространялось довольно медленно и даже относилось **к "манерному" петербургскому говору.**

И когда же оно зафиксировано **в толковых словарях**?

Comment: Исправлена ошибка: ударение, конечно же, смещается не первый слог.

Comment: Уважаемые участники форума, неужели никто не знает, с какого времени в письменных источниках  упоминается слово "творог"?

Answer (score 1):

Из лекции Зализняка: «Ударение „тво́рог‟ выдаёт мгновенно для историка языка свою позднейшесть. А именно: дело в том, что в слове „творо́г‟ корень „тва́р‟ и он [творог] писался „**тваро́г**‟ и произносился „тваро́г‟».

https://tvkultura.ru/video/show/brand_id/20898/episode_id/973669/video_id/983735/

Т. е. ударение движется в *противоположном* направлении. Судя по тому, что в некоторых источниках (на основании признания нормативности обоих вариантов) первым ставится вариант с ударением на первом слоге, некоторая часть авторов руководствуется личным (регионально-обусловленным) предпочтением. У Фасмера - словарная статья "тваро́г" (http://www.gidropraktikum.narod.ru/etymology.htm - в современном издании с доп. от Трубачева двоякое ударение могло быть добавлено); в ней приводится и белорусский вариант ударения - только на первом слоге.

> Шанский Н.М., Иванов В.В., Шанская Т.В. Краткий этимологический
>   словарь русского языка, 1975
>
> **Тво́ро́г.** Восходит к общеслав. *тварогъ*
>   с изменением *а* в *о* в результате переноса ударения (ср. диал.
>   *плотит, котит* и т. п.). Образовано с помощью суф. *-огъ* от той же основы, но с перегласовкой, что и творить (в диалектах имеющего также
>   значение "растворять, месить, замешивать", см. растворить). Ср. диал.
>   утвар - "кислое тесто".

Comment: Так почему смещается ударение?  Когда слово появилось в языке, оно имело ударение на втором слоге, вероятно, по аналогии с источником. (Есть даже предположение, что изначально существовали  оба варианта). Но потом по каким-то причинам (фонетическим, семантическим) носители языка стали предпочитать первый слог, поэтому пришлось вносить изменения в словари. Так что это за причины? А про даты ничего не можете сказать? Хотя бы во времена Пушкина существовало слово "творог"?

Comment: Я помню, что когда-то видел в словаре Даля только один вариант, ясно какой. Сейчас в сети попадаются только издания, где вторым добавлен вариант с ударением на первом слоге (надо искать старый сканы старых изданий). Сеть полнится передаваемыми по цепочке рассуждениями, что именно Даль предложил второй вариант и добавил его (думаю, это неправда). Найти хронологию трудно, но мне кажется, что в нормативы второй вариант стал добавляться во 2 половине 20 века. Я бы поискал справочник для телевидения и радиовещания, обязательный для дикторов, возможно, там только один вариант.

Comment: @Jasmin "носители языка стали предпочитать первый слог" - не согласен. нормативное ударение в слове творОг пока еще на втором слоге. твОрог в совр. орфоэпических словарях помечается как "допуст." (БОСРЯ-2, ОСРЯ-10).

Comment: @Jasmin гадать не будем о датах. Вот здесь http://iling.spb.ru/vocabula/bas/pdf/15.pdf (176-177). Поликарпов 1704 тварОгъ, Целлариус 1771 творОг. В произведениях самого Пушкина слово творог не встречается ни разу (СПП-2).

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Из ПЦСС РЯ.)

Упомянутый Федор Шимкевич в «Корнеслове русскаго языка» в конце обширной статьи даёт такое к ней дополнение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Даю скрины (без ответа) как повод продолжения разговора.

Comment: Спасибо, здесь речь идет, вероятно, об этимологическом словаре (это уже 1842 год).Но очень интересно, когда оно появилось в толковом словаре.